# Does Algolia support pivot and relational tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algolia

I am using laravel php to build a web app and I am using algolia as  a search service. However I can't make algolia return results based on pivot tables and foreign id in other tables.So my question is it true that algolia at the moment doesn't support pivot and relational tables?Or am I not getting this right and it's totally my fault?
thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines are initially not designed to handle relations: it's something databases are doing great but it has a big cost at query time.

For performance reasons, the Algolia engine doesn't support such kind of relations. The best way to go is therefore to denormalize your data before pushing it to Algolia.

**Example:**

You have a `users(id, name)` & a `posts(id, author_id, content)` SQL table and you want to search into the posts while displaying both the post content and the author's name.

You should do a `JOIN` on your side to resolve the author's name and push a single `{ "objectID": 42, "content": "...", "author_name": "<fetched from users table>" }` object to Algolia.